# How to validate email while updating in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have 2 tables named `area_managers` and `shopkeepers`. I want to `validate email` from `area_managers` while updating in a way so that it doesn't match with the email of `shopkeepers` and `area_managers` table. I tried the following way but it doesn't even allow the existed email of the respective user.

```
   public function update(Request $request, AreaManager $areaManager)
    {
        $request->validate([   
     'email'=>'required|email|unique:shopkeepers,email|unique:area_managers,email,'.$areaManager->id,
        ]);
        $areaManager-> email = $request->email;
        $areaManager->update();
        return redirect()->route('area_manager.edit',$areaManager->id);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you would have to ignore the current user's record from the unique rule, the docs explain how to do this for that rule

Comment: So you need to validation unique while updating right ?

Comment: ManojKiran, yes. validate unique from 2 tables while updating.

Comment: This looks like it should be working. What is `$areaManager`? Include all the relevant code, and show where this code is. A controller method I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick check could be something like this:

```
$checkAreaManagers = DB::table('area_managers')->where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
$checkShopkeepers = DB::table('shopkeepers')->where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();

if ($checkAreaManagers === null || $checkShopkeepers === null) {
  
   // Proceed with the update
   
    $areaManager->email = $request->email;
    $areaManager->save();
}

if ($checkAreaManagers !== null || $checkShopkeepers !== null) {
  
   // Cancel the update (Your logic here)
   
   dd('Duplicate found');

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should make a role with this command:

> php artisan make:rule rolename

then in passes method set your query and then use in validator